# Llightbox открывает исходник изображения

Tags: jquery, lightbox

В плагине lightbox при нажатии на изображение колесиком мышки открывается его исходник в новом окне, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии колесиком на изображение открывалось модальное как при нажатии ЛКМ?

[Страница с плагином](https://parket.tomsk.ru/gikori-sero-korichnevyj275)

Пробовал так сделать, не помогло.

```
jQuery('#gallery a').on("mousedown", function(e) {
      if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
        return false;
      }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Код в студию. А также ссылку на конкретный плагин lightbox который Вы используете, lightbox - это название семейства штук, а не конкретной штуки